# MySQL - Recovering from failed drop database

Tags: mysql

Ok, so I had a very large (40GB) database containing 1 table. I went to the Windows MySQL command prompt and typed:

```
drop database very_large_db;
```

I waited a few minutes and it came back with an error. I'm sorry but I forgot to record the error number. It then tried to reconnect and was unable to re-connect to the MySQL command prompt. I then rebooted the computer, went back to the command prompt, and tried to drop the database again. At this point, it just kicked me out and the MySQL service stopped (verified in services.msc). Next, I decided to go to the MySQL data directory in Windows Explorer and manually delete the database directory. It deleted no problem, and when I perform a "show databases;" command in the MySQL command prompt, it is no longer there.

Is there anything else I need to do to make sure the database was properly deleted? Is there any chance I corrupted any other databases in MySQL?

Thanks

Comment: Empty the bin and check the space on the disk.

Comment: does `Information_schema` still have entries for the deleted database and its tables? You may want to clean that up as well.

Comment: Well now I'm noticing it takes forever for mysql to start, and it says in the error log "Could not find a valid tablespace file for..."

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the directory is equivalent to DROP TABLE. Try this: create a sub-directory in data and run 'SHOW DATABASES;' you'll see that MySQL just considers the directory to be a database.